# MIMIC-III Inputevents_mv 'Rewritten' value

Tags: mimic-iii

Can anyone clarify how the 'Rewritten' value in the statusdescription column impacts the data? It appears impossible to ascertain the final "approved" sequence of events in a particular fluid delivery.  The time sequence of multiple rewritten columns from a particular linkorderid seem to have overlapping time segments with no way to determine which ones are the accurate (Read final set accepted by the clinicians) time / rate / amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth for anyone else who stumbles upon this question and want an answer, see https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/issues/47#issuecomment-282734892

> As far as we know, all rewritten rows should only be used for audit
>   purposes, i.e. these rows correspond to drug doses never being given
>   to patients. We are considering removing this audit trail in the
>   future as its use in research seems limited and it only acts to create
>   a confusing table.

So in my own analysis, since I care about what the patient received, I exclude those that have `Rewritten` in the column `statusdescription`. However, I also only include `cancelreason = 0`. The corresponding code for cancelreason is unclear, but if there's any reason for cancelling it then in my analysis I do not include it.